# How to make specgram fill entire figure area with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting specgram usign the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
fig.clf()
plot = plt.subplot(111)
plt.specgram(data, NFFT = 256, Fs = 120000)
plot.grid(False, which="major")
plot.set_xlabel(r'\textit{Time (s)}', labelpad=6)
plot.set_ylabel(r'\textit{{Frequency (Hz)}}', labelpad=6)
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig('specgram.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

But the specgram does not fill the entire figure area as shown below:

[image]

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [set_xlim](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) to the maximum value of your data.